# jQuery address plugin -- Not working when content is replaced

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-address

I've been using the jQuery address plugin to enable back-button support, which has been working except for when the link is in the AJAX content area.  For example

```
<div id="content">
  <a href="example.html" rel="address:example.html" onclick="ajaxLoad(this);">link</a>
</div>
```

where ajaxLoad replaces `content` with the content of `example.html`.  When I try to do this, the address bar does not change, and the back button just goes to the last instance of a link outside the content area.

Is there a way to make this work?

**EDIT:**

Plugin: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Example ajaxLoad function:

```
function ajaxLoad(obj)
{
    $.get(obj, function(data)
    {   
        $("#main").html(data);
    }); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you give a link to the said plugin? and the definition of `ajaxLoad()`...

Comment: I've added the information to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using context-sensitive window.location.

Modified ajaxLoad:

```
function ajaxLoad(obj, inline)
{
    if(!inline)
        window.location='#/'+obj.rel.substring(8);
    else
    {
        $.get(obj, function(data)
        {   
            $("#main").html(data);
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then the handler for the initial page load, and when the back/forward buttons are used:

```
$.address.externalChange(function(event)
{
    var url = event.value.substring(1); //strips the leading slash
    if(url == "")
        url = 'index.php';
    loadPage(url, true);
});
```

I don't know if this is the best method, but it works.